# Reverse tetrads (nybbles) to get a mirrored hex using bit manipulations only

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I was given an interesting task to help somebody with; here it is:

> Write a function to reverse tetrads in a number only using bit manipulations, constants, ~ ! * + - sizeof() << >> & ^ and |.
>
> If, do, while, for, goto, switch etc. are not allowed, no macros, c++ functions (even compiler's intristic functions), &&, ||, ternary, and any other data types and structures, except for unsigned int.

Here is what I've got, it works, but it uses one tiny loop and that is a problem...

```
unsigned ReverseTetrads(unsigned x)
{
   unsigned reversed = x&0xF;

   while ((x >>= 4) != 0) {
      reversed <<= 4;
      reversed |= x&0xF;
   }

   return reversed;
}
```

Example:

> 0x12ABCD should be reversed to 0xDCBA21

Comment: Just unroll the loop, and you're done. You know the maximum number one can put into `unsigned int`, so, you can calculate, how many steps it would take `x` to become zero.

Comment: does "unsigned x" is the same as "unsigned int x"? can you just declare it like that?

Comment: @Felipe Yes, it's valid.

Comment: @ForceBru the bigger `x`, the more it takes for it to become `0`. Like as if `x` was `0x12`, it wouldn't even need the loop since all of the `1`s are in the first byte of it - looping till the end in such situation would lead to result `0x120000000` instead of `0x12`

Comment: Are the test cases validated? It seems weird to say that the leading zeroes don't count.

Comment: Ignoring the leading zeros seems very strange to me too. This question doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @harold @Mus campester Yes, we don't need leading zeroes since they become trailing zeroes after the "mirroring" of tetrads. Here is an example:
If we pass `0x12` (`0x000000012`) to a function, it should return `0x21`, but if we invert leading zeroes too, that would be `0x210000000`.

Comment: That's an odd way to put it though - seems to me that you *do* need the leading zeroes, precisely *because* they become trailing zeroes (which are significant). But if you're sure this is what the assignment means then fair enough

Comment: @harold Exactly, that's the way professor described it :/
Full tetrad reversal is indeed really simple and I would need to "Just unroll the loop" as ForceBru said in that case. But the task is more about "Get a  mirrored HEX"

Comment: Ok well how about this, unroll the loop and "fake" the conditional by multiplying the shift count and the right hand side of the OR by `!!x` (so it does nothing once `x` reaches zero). Kind of an ugly way to do it perhaps, but it's a start

Comment: The terminology "tetrad" is interesting since they are ordinarily called nybbles or hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Or just the shift count, now that I think it over. If `x` is zero anyway it's not going to do anything to `reversed` of course.

Comment: @DietrichEpp oh, thanks, that's a _faux amis_ (translation fault) I'll look out for

Comment: @harold trying it out, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reverse the tetrads using the standard bit-hack, ignoring leading zeros: swap the top and bottom 16 bits, then swap the top and bottom bytes within each 16 bits, then the top and bottom nybble within each byte.

Then you can get rid of the leading zeros (which are now trailing zeros) by checking if the bottom 16 bits, the bottom byte and then bottom nybble are zero and shifting appropriately. We can rely on the fact that !x evaluates to 1 for a value of 0, and 0 otherwise.

```
unsigned int ReverseTetrads(unsigned int x)
{
    // reverse tetrads ignoring leading zeros
    x = (x << 16) | (x >> 16);
    x = ((x << 8) & 0xff00ff00) | ((x >> 8) & 0x00ff00ff);
    x = ((x << 4) & 0xf0f0f0f0) | ((x >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f);

    // get rid of the leading zeros (which are now trailing zeros)
    x >>= !(x & 0x0000ffff) * 16;
    x >>= !(x & 0x000000ff) * 8;
    x >>= !(x & 0x0000000f) * 4;

    return x;
}
```

According to the question, `*` is allowed, but if you think it doesn't count as bit-manipulation then you can substitute `x >>= !(x & 0x0000ffff) << 4;` for `x >>= !(x & 0x0000ffff) * 16;` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with:

```
unsigned ReverseTetrads(unsigned x)
{
   unsigned
      reversed = x&0xF,
      offsets = 0;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed <<= 4;
   x >>= 4;
   offsets += !!x;
   reversed |= x&0xF;

   reversed >>= (7 - offsets) * 4;

   return reversed;
}
```

Works perfectly for any `unsigned int`.